# While loop in FPDF retrieve data only first time.It prints the table in pdf perfectly but doesn't input the data retrieved after first time

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am printing a table filled with the data retrieved from database in PDF using FPDF library. I want this code to run until the end and print the data of students in groups in the table.It is retrieving and printing the data perfectly for the first group but for the other groups it prints only the table and doesn't populate it with the data.
here is my code.

```
session_start();
require ('../make_db_connection.php');
require ("../fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM student_data");
$num=$res->num_rows;
while ($num > 0)
{
    $pdf->AddPage();

    if ($num != 0)
    {
        $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
        $title=$row['title'];
        $date=$row['sub_date'];
        $supervisor=$row['supervisor'];
        $res = $conn->query("SELECT name,roll_no,abstract FROM student_data WHERE title='".$title."' AND supervisor='".$supervisor."'");
    }
    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetMargins(30,0,20);
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',14);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'',0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(0,7,"FYP Evaluation Sheet",0,1,'C');
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',13);
    $pdf->Cell(0,4,'',0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(40,7,"GR#:",0,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,"Project Title:",0,0,'L');
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',11);
    $pdf->MultiCell(90,7,$title,'','L',FALSE);
    //Table
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',13);
    $pdf->Cell(0,4,'',0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(40,7,"Individuals:",0,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'',0,1);
    $x=$pdf->GetX();
    $y=$pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell(35,10, 'Reg#','LRTB','C',TRUE);
    $pdf->SetXY($x+35,$y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(70,10, 'Name','LTB','C', TRUE);
    $pdf->SetXY($x+105,$y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(50,10, 'Marks & Comments','LRTB','C', TRUE);
    $pdf->MultiCell(0,0, '','R',FALSE);
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',10);
    $x=$pdf->GetX();
    $y=$pdf->GetY();
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $student1=$row['name']; 
    $student1_rollno=$row['roll_no'];
    $num=$num-1;
    $pdf->MultiCell(35,8,$student1_rollno,'LRB','C',0);
    $pdf->SetXY($x+35,$y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(70,8,$student1,'B','C', 0);
    $pdf->SetXY($x+105,$y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(50,8,'','LRB','L', 0);
    $x=$pdf->GetX();
    $y=$pdf->GetY();
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    if($row)
    {
        $student2=$row['name']; 
        $student2_rollno=$row['roll_no'];
        $pdf->MultiCell(35,8,$student2_rollno,'LRB','C',0);
        $pdf->SetXY($x+35,$y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(70,8,$student2,'B','C', 0);
        $pdf->SetXY($x+105,$y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(50,8,'','LRB','L', 0);
        $num=$num-1;
    }
    $pdf->MultiCell(100,8, 'Note: Please fill the form and submit with name and   signature.','','L', 0);

}
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->output();
```

what am I doing wrong in this code?I can't figure out!

Comment: You run a query for `SELECT * from student_data` but then in that `while` loop, using the same variable name `$res`, you then run a different `SELECT`. That's a problem.

Comment: @MariM ohh totally ignored that.Thank you that solved the problem.

Comment: Since that seemed to solve the problem, I've gone ahead and provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put my answer here since my comment on OP worked out.

You used the `$res` variable to store results for a query within the `while` loop, which overwrites the previously stored result.